# Keyboard shortcut for "Add CC recipient" in Inbox By Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

In the classic Gmail web interface on a PC, it was possible to show and set the focus to the CC: field by pressing Ctrl+Shift+C.

This doesn't work in Inbox By Gmail.

Is there a way to accomplish this task with the keyboard in Inbox By Gmail?

Comment: **Inbox by Gmail** was retired in April, 2019 and is no longer available.

Answer (score 7):

Starting with the focus on the To field:

1. Press Shift+Tab (to set the focus to the "hide arrow" in the top right corner of the compose overlay)
2. Press Enter (to activate the "hide arrow" and show the hidden fields)
3. Press Tab (to set the focus to the CC: field)

Obviously, this isn't ideal, however!

Comment: As of 7/16/2018, step 3 is optional. Caret is already focused into the CC field after I press ENTER in step 2.

Answer (score -1):

Similar to Jon, but faster since it removes one step:

(Shift) + (Tab) ........THEN....... (Enter)

Comment: Without the last step the cursor stays in To: field, it doesn' t move to the CC: field.